Next.js App Directory - Loading UI does not work consistently with route group
If I have the following route structure:
app/
└── deals/
    ├── all/
    │   └── page.tsx
    ├── some/
    │   └── page.tsx
    ├── other/
    │   └── page.tsx
    ├── layout.tsx
    └── loading.tsx

The streaming-loading functionality works as expected. When I navigate from /deals/all to /deals/some, I "immediately" get a loading UI based on loading.tsx. However, if I add route groups to the mix, like so:
app/
└── (foo)/
    ├── deals/
    │   ├── all/
    │   │   └── page.tsx
    │   ├── some/
    │   │   └── page.tsx
    │   └── other/
    │       └── page.tsx
    ├── blogs/
    │   ├── all/
    │   │   └── page.tsx
    │   └── some/
    │       └── page.tsx
    ├── layout.tsx
    └── loading.tsx

I still get an initial loading UI when opening /deals/all for the first time, however the loading UI no longer shows up when navigating from /deals/all to /deals/some.
